# gzuncompress data error

Tags: php, mysql

Просьба помочь с ошибкой: вылезает `gzuncompress() [function.gzuncompress]: data error`.
Логика скрипта такова: данные массива сжимаются в строку, потом пакуются gzcompress и пишутся в БД в поле типа BLOB. Затем данные из этого поля извлекаются, разжимаются gzuncompress и переводятся в массив для работы с ним. Но при разжатии gzuncompress'ом возникает данная ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?

Запись:

```
$db->exec('
    update `table`
    set `code` = "' . gzcompress(json_encode($_SESSION['order'])) . '"
    where
        `id` = ' . $id . '
');
```

Чтение:

```
$camp = $db->execAndReturnAssoc('
    select `code`
    from `table`
    where
        `id` = ' . $id . '
    limit 0,1
');
$camp = json_decode(gzuncompress($camp['code']), true);
```

Comment: Временным решением пока что служит base64_encode(gzcompress(...)). Но хотелось бы обойтись без этой функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользуюсь `base64_encode(gzcompress(json_encode($code)))`, $code - массив. Вроде, нормально работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db->exec('
    update `table`
    set `code` = "' . mysql_real_escape_string( gzcompress(json_encode($_SESSION['order']))
) . '"
    where
        `id` = ' . $id . '
');
```

Comment: Не, не сильно помогло. В БД записался x, а остальные символы были "съедены".

Answer (score 1):

может уже не актуально, а может кому поможет...

1. нужно выполнить SET NAMES 'utf8' или SET NAMES 'binary' перед выполнением запросов к базе, это задаст кодировку соединения client/server, но 'binary', когда все данные идут как бинарные, если часть запроса идет как обычные строковые данные, тогда ВОЗМОЖНО лучше в utf8. думаю, здесь нужно дополнительные проверки или спрсоить у тех, кто больше с кодировками работал
2. это mysql_real_escape_string( ) обязательно!
3. колонка для сжатых данных должна иметь формат blob или другие бинарные, так как gzcompress возвращает строку, которая за пределами utf8 и база данные выдаст ошибку о зарпещенных символах
4. проверял на PHP 5.6, MySQL 5.6
5. все это выполнял на чистом mysqli без всяких оберток и прочего

   - $MySQL    = new mysqli(host, login, pass, db_name, port);
   - check connection error;
   - $MySQL->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
   - $query = "...";
   - $query_result = $MySQL->query($query);
     на получение:
   - $query_result->fetch_assoc();
   - ну дальше все как обычно...

по этой ссылке https://mariolurig.com/coding/mysqli-and-blob-binary-database-fields/ предлогают подготовленые запросы, у меня все работает без них...